# Defining polymorphic relationships in Laravel with models on custom namespaces

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4

I have Eloquent models on custom namespaces. By that I mean that, for example, my Users model is in `Admin\User`. Each user has, either a Member or an Admin associated with it. These later models are on the same namespace as the user model: `Admin\Member` and `Admin\Admin`.

I have defined the relationships as follows

```
namespace Admin;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Admin extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Admin\User', 'model');
    }
}

class Member extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Admin\User', 'model');
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I do:

```
$member = Member::find($id);
```

`$member->user` is `NULL`.

Anything else I need to define? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I'm having the same issue (using morphMany() btw) and while it is supposed to be quite simple I'm stuck...

Comment: Does it work when you remove the namespace declaration?

Comment: Actually, $member->user returning null means no user associated with the member were found. If it can't find the class it throws an exception.

Comment: I did get it working, I don't know exactly how but be sure to re-migrate your tables and run composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers...

I've ran into this problem before with namespaced models. With polymorphic relationships, Laravel is storing the XXX-able_id and XXX-able_type in the table. The XXX-able_type is generally the *fully qualified name of the model*, not just the class name. So, in this case, you'll need to check that the value in that column is indeed `Admin\User` and not just `User`.

In your case, remigrating simply caused the models to get inserted with their fully-qualified name, rather than just the class name.

Hope this helps.